# Lucene 30 fuzzy search

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, fuzzy-search

I user LUCENE_30 for my search engine but i cannot make fuzzy search.How can i make it work?
I tried use GetFuzzyQuery but nothing happens.As i see is not supported.

Here my code :

```
if (searchQuery.Length < 3)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("none");
            }
            FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(_indexFileLocation));

            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);
            var analyzer = new RussianAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);

            var query = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, searchQuery, new[] {"Title" }, new[] { Occur.SHOULD }, analyzer);



            var hits = searcher.Search(query, 11110);
            var dto = new PerformSearchResultDto();
            dto.SearchResults = new List<SearchResult>();
            dto.Total = hits.TotalHits;

            for (int i = pagesize * page; i < hits.TotalHits && i < pagesize * page + pagesize; i++)
            {
                //  Document doc = hits.Doc(i);
                int docId = hits.ScoreDocs[i].Doc;
                var doc = searcher.Doc(docId);
                var result = new SearchResult();
                result.Title = doc.Get("Title");
                result.Type = doc.Get("Type");
                result.Href = doc.Get("Href");
                result.LastModified = doc.Get("LastModified");
                result.Site = doc.Get("Site");
                result.City = doc.Get("City");
                //result.Region = doc.Get("Region");
                result.Content = doc.Get("Content");
                result.NoIndex = Convert.ToBoolean(doc.Get("NoIndex"));
                dto.SearchResults.Add(result);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy queries certainly are supported.  See the [`FuzzyQuery`](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d0/db9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_fuzzy_query.html) class.

The query parser also [supports fuzzy queries](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches), simply with a tilde appended: `misspeled~`